# Shopify-App Yearly Membership plan issue with UsageCharge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-activemerchant

I have added Yearly Membership plan using UsageCharge by setting the recurring price to "0" and capped_amount = "120.00" and usage price to "120.0" but,  I think it will be very confusing in the confirmation page they'll see: 'Up to USD 120 every 30 days'. It must be 'Up to $120 every year'. Please give me solution as soon as possible, or tell me the best approach for implementing Yearly membership recurring charge.[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylaxz.png)

Answer (score 1):

Does it not make more to sense to use a ONE-TIME payment of 120.00 but inform the customer that that is actually a one-time payment for a year. And then when their year is up, just hit them up with another ONE-TIME charge?

One time charges are pretty much set for this kind of thing are they not? Anytime you want to bill the customer for some "thing" your App does, you can use this.